# Customize login block's position in page.tpl

Tags: forms, users

I'm trying to position my login block in my page.tpl file. Everytime I insert the code

`<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login')); ?>`

in my page.tpl file. It throws an error. The error it throws is

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include() (line 79 of C:..\sites\all\themes\neptune\templates\page.tpl.php).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what error it throws?

Comment: Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include() (line 79 of C:\..\sites\all\themes\neptune\templates\page.tpl.php).

Comment: @nabeela you should add the details to your post. Please edit your question and add details.(instead of in comments)

Comment: Sorry about that @KrishnaMohan

Comment: @nabeela nothing to be sorry about that. I just wanted to notify you. :)

Comment: Why don't you place block as usual, using admin interface and regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if(!user_is_logged_in() ){
    $userLoginForm = drupal_get_form('user_login');
    print drupal_render($userLoginForm);
}
```

because [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) receives argument as reference..

Comment: thanks it worked. If you don't mind telling me..is there a way to change the style of the form?

Comment: @nabeela what style? With CSS you mean?

Comment: When I put this code, the only thing I see is the username, password and submit fields. the "Register" and "Forgot your Password" fields are not there. So how can include that in this

Comment: ok, I understand. You should include User login block instead of User login form to your .tpl.php file..

Comment: Yess thats exactly what I want..how do I include that user login block in my page.tpl.php?

Comment: @nabeela this can be done easily in AdminUI (Structure->Blocks), or if you want to do it in code and don't know how to do it you can post another question. Or you want me to add it here?

Comment: I would like to this in code. Cause I wanna put the user login block in a specific place. It'll be great if you can add it here :) ..but if you want I can post another question

Comment: @nabeela you better post another question, I'll answer it with pleasure:)

Comment: Alright..here's my question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130153/add-and-customize-login-block-on-page-tpl