# Add and customize login block on page.tpl

Tags: forms, users

I'm trying to add the user login block in my page.tpl file. I've tried inserting the following code but  the only thing I see is the username, password and submit fields. The "Register" and "Forgot your Password" fields are not there. And I would like to do this in code form. Cause I wanna put the user login block in a specific place.

```
if(!user_is_logged_in() ){
    $userLoginForm = drupal_get_form('user_login');
    print drupal_render($userLoginForm);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't do it. Go to /admin/structure/block and place "User login" block in region you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
$block = block_load('user', 'login');
$block = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
$block_build = _block_get_renderable_array($block);

print drupal_render($block_build);
```

this will generate a block with title and contexual links also..

Comment: I think it is a bad thing to do. Template should never need particular blocks available. Proper way would be to render a region, and use admin interface to put a block in that region.

Comment: @Mołot I know, I answered his/her previuos question, [read](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/130139/7205) the comments, please..

Comment: @Mołot this can be done in `TEMPLATE_preprocess_page` function, not in tpl file..

Comment: Actually, comments are "second-class citizens", if something is not in question or answer, it is next to non-existent. And it seems OP is coding against environment and nobody bothered to tell him, you just guide him deeper into problems and hard to manage solutions.

Comment: @Mołot I am not trying to teach him, I'm just answering the question, I don't think drupal.stackexchange.com is a tutorial site, and also he is not asking how to properly assign a block to region

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble. Just trying to figure things out. I'll try to look into the TEMPLATE_preprocess_page function. ..btw I'm a "her" :)

Comment: @nabeela oops, I'm sorry for the "he"..