# Block print on page.tpl file

Tags: views, theming

I have created a block for adding image from drupal backend with title name "image". Now i want to add this block into page.tpl.
How can i do that by using code.

Comment: I'd advise doing it from `admin/structure/block`. Read [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130153/add-and-customize-login-block-on-page-tpl/130154#130154), espacially the comments, if you really want to do it in code..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code

```
$imageblock = block_load('block', '155');
$output =  drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($imageblock))));
```

$output will have the generate html for the block . This can be rendered in the template file using

```
 print $output;
```

If the block is created using views, you may have to use `$imageblock = block_load('views', 'block_name');` instead of loading the block using the block id.